# CloudWatch: metrics from agent not available in dashboard, but available in alarms

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I've set free tier micro instance, and on it cloud watch agent was configured, which should send data to cloud watch, but for some reason data is not available there. Only the measure keys are passed correctly as in configuration (earlier only general was available in metrics dropdowns, and I'm interested in disk free space to set some alerts).

Config:

```
$ cat /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json

{
  "agent": {
    "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
    "run_as_user": "root"
  },
  "metrics": {
    "append_dimensions": {
      "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
      "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
      "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
      "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
    },
    "metrics_collected": {
      "collectd": {
        "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60
      },
      "disk": {
        "measurement": [
          "used_percent"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "resources": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "mem": {
        "measurement": [
          "mem_used_percent"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60
      },
      "statsd": {
        "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60,
        "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
        "service_address": ":8125"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Status after agent started:

```
{
  "status": "running",
  "starttime": "2021-05-06T11:54:40+0000",
  "configstatus": "configured",
  "cwoc_status": "stopped",
  "cwoc_starttime": "",
  "cwoc_configstatus": "not configured",
  "version": "1.247347.4"
}
```

Logs:

```
2021/05/06 11:54:41 I! I! Detected the instance is EC2
2021/05/06 11:54:41 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json ...
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json does not exist or cannot read. Skipping it.
2021/05/06 11:54:41 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_config.json ...
Valid Json input schema.
I! Detecting run_as_user...
No csm configuration found.
No log configuration found.
Configuration validation first phase succeeded
 
2021/05/06 11:54:41 I! Config has been translated into TOML /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml 
2021/05/06 11:54:41 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json ...
2021/05/06 11:54:41 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_config.json ...
2021/05/06 11:54:41 I! Detected runAsUser: root
2021/05/06 11:54:41 I! Changing ownership of [/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/var] to root:root
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! Starting AmazonCloudWatchAgent 1.247347.4
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! Loaded inputs: disk mem socket_listener statsd
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! Loaded aggregators: 
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! Loaded processors: ec2tagger
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! Loaded outputs: cloudwatch
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! Tags enabled: host=ip-172-11-11-111.ec2.internal
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:1m0s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"ip-172-11-11-111.ec2.internal", Flush Interval:1s
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! [logagent] starting
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! [processors.ec2tagger] ec2tagger: EC2 tagger has started initialization.
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! cloudwatch: get unique roll up list []
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! [inputs.socket_listener] Listening on udp://127.0.0.1:25826
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! Started the statsd service on :8125
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! cloudwatch: publish with ForceFlushInterval: 1m0s, Publish Jitter: 38s
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! Statsd listener listening on:  [::]:8125
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! [processors.ec2tagger] ec2tagger: Initial retrieval of tags succeded
2021-05-06T11:54:42Z I! [processors.ec2tagger] ec2tagger: EC2 tagger has started, finished initial retrieval of tags and Volumes
```

IAM of EC2 instance policies I guess more then required: AmazonEC2FullAccess, **CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy**, CloudWatchFullAccess, CloudWatchActionsEC2Access, CloudWatchLogsFullAccess, CloudWatchEventsFullAccess, EC2InstanceConnect

CloudWatch metrics:
[image: disk_used_percent]

I appreciate any help/hint.

**Edit:** actually metrics are stored, in alarms I can see them, but not sure why they are not available for instance in dashboard as on previous image.

Metrics in alarms:
[image: Metrics in alarms]

Comment: I have the same scenario with you, only can view the data in alarm, have you figure out any solution?